# How to know the exact statement fired in Data app block?

Tags: sql, daab

We are using "Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block" to access SQL Server database. In DataAccess layer, we are calling application block's API. Internally it must be resolving the command and parameters into SQL statement.

How can I know what SQL query goes to database?

Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 1):

One way:

Run profiler on SQL Server, start a trace and add even SQL:Batchstarting. In the trace data look at the TextData column

see image below of what it looks like

[image]